# Material action bar in eclipse

Tags: android

How to create android material design action bar in eclipse

I'm attaching an image here, I'm trying like this!
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Update your android sdk to latest one, and use actionbar activity of updated appcompact

Comment: i have updated sdk. i want to run this in mini target version 14

Answer (score 0):

For navigation drawer you just need to update android-support library.

For material action bar see [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html)

Sample code you can see [here](https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template) this is more about navigation drawer but it also contains code for toolbar

Comment: The sample code you have given is for android studio.